# Are there any successful applications of transformers of small size (<10k weights)?

Tags: applications, transformer, sequence-modeling, efficiency, seq2seq

In the problems of NLP and sequence modeling, the Transformer architectures based on the **self-attention mechanism** (proposed in [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)) have achieved impressive results and now are the first choices in this sort of problem.

However, most of the architectures, which appear in the literature, have a lot of parameters and are aimed at solving rather complicated tasks of language modeling ([[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805), [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14165)). These models have a large number of parameters and are computationally expensive.

There exist multiple approaches to reduce the computational complexity of these models, like [knowledge distillation](https://medium.com/pytorch/bert-distillation-with-catalyst-c6f30c985854?sk=1a28469ac8c0e6e6ad35bd26dfd95dd9) or multiple approaches to deal with the $O(n^2)$
computational complexity of the self-attention ([[3]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04768), [[4]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14794)).

However, these models are still aimed at language modeling and require quite a lot of parameters.

I wonder whether there are successful applications of transformers with a very small number of parameters (1k-10k), in the signal processing applications, where inference has to be performed in a very fast way, hence heavy and computationally expensive models are not allowed.

So far, the common approaches are CNN or RNN architectures, but I wonder whether there are some results, where lightweight transformers have achieved SOTA results for these extremely small models.